# Brightcove video docking in AMP

Tags: amp-html

Is video docking available for amp-brightcove component in AMP?

I can see it availabe on the amp-video component and some commits about the video interface but can't see any mention on video docking.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by video docking?

Comment: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/amp-pages-will-soon-support-video-docking-sticky-ads-more/274867/ and https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/10174

Comment: It is supported now